# row values from range based on another row in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My two sample df are as below.

df1

```
Column1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

df2

```
Column 1   Column2 
1            A 
2            B
3            C
4            D
5            E
6            F
7            G
8            H
9            I
10           J
```

What I want is merge two dfs on df1, which is quite simple. But if the value is not found in df2 i want to look into a range.
e.g. if NaN then it should further look whether it is between 11 to 13 then it should "C" if its between 14 to 18 it should return "D" and if between 19-25 result should be "E".

Comment: Salam, I don't think you can do this with a merge, you'd have to create a secondary mapping field to add this in or create another dataframe with your desired merges. .

Comment: W/Salam, How do I do it?

Comment: whats the logic for the grouping? of your NaN values? i don't see a pattern from 11-13, 14-18 19-25 etc?

Comment: NaN is not necessary at first step I can either look into the range first.

Comment: to be exact 
```
5700 to 5799.99
``` 
should return 6%

6100 to 6299.9999 should return 7% and similarly 5311 to 6399.999 will answer as 6%

Answer (score 2):

You need to use merge and replace the NaNs with `fillna()`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': range(1,26)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': range(1,11),
                    'Column2': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']})

df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Column1'], how='left')
fill_dict = {11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C',
             14: 'D', 15: 'D', 16: 'D', 17: 'D', 18: 'D',
             19: 'E', 20: 'E', 21: 'E', 22: 'E', 23: 'E', 24: 'E', 25: 'E'}

df1['Column2'] = df1.replace({'Column1':fill_dict})

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Column1 Column2
0         1       1
1         2       2
2         3       3
3         4       4
4         5       5
5         6       6
6         7       7
7         8       8
8         9       9
9        10      10
10       11       C
11       12       C
12       13       C
13       14       D
14       15       D
15       16       D
16       17       D
17       18       D
18       19       E
19       20       E
20       21       E
21       22       E
22       23       E
23       24       E
24       25       E
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you have a range to create the fill_dict dictionary you can use `dict.fromkeys()`

```
fill_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(11,14),'C')
fill_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(range(14,19),'D'))
fill_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(range(19,26),'E'))
```

Or you can also use list comprehension to create the fill_dict dict

```
fill_dict = dict([(i, 'C') for i in range(11, 14)] + 
                 [(i, 'D') for i in range(14, 19)] + 
                 [(i, 'E') for i in range(19, 26)])
```

**EDIT 2:**

Based on our chat conversation, can you please try this:

Instead of creating the dict with range of int's, as your data has float values, I thought of using `np.arange()` but identifying the correct key with the decimal precision was a bit problematic. So, I thought of writing a function to generate the keys. I am sure this is not efficient in terms of performance. But it gets the job done. There should be some other effective solution for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import decimal

def gen_float_range(start, stop, step):
  while start < stop:
    yield float(start)
    start += decimal.Decimal(step)

base1 = pd.DataFrame({'HS CODE': [5004.0000,5005.0000,5006.0000,5007.1000,5007.2000,6115.950,6115.950,6115.960,6115.960,6115.950]})
base2 = pd.DataFrame({'HS CODE': [5004.0000,5005.0000,5006.0000,5007.1000,5007.2000],
                      '%age': 0.4})

base1 = base1.merge(base2, on=['HS CODE'], how='left')

fill_dict = dict.fromkeys(list(gen_float_range(6110,6121,0.0001)),'0.06')
# base1['%age'] = base1.replace({'HS CODE':fill_dict})
base1['%age'] = base1['%age'].fillna(base1['HS CODE'].map(fill_dict))
print(base1)
```

Output:

```
   HS CODE  %age
0  5004.00   0.4
1  5005.00   0.4
2  5006.00   0.4
3  5007.10   0.4
4  5007.20   0.4
5  6115.95  0.06
6  6115.95  0.06
7  6115.96  0.06
8  6115.96  0.06
9  6115.95  0.06
```

You have to create the fill_dict with the different ranges and append to your fill_dict using the `start` and `stop` values and the `step` should be how you would increment. Based on the data that you shared, I assumed the step will be 0.0001, but this is going to be too much for the dict. You can look at ways for reducing the `step` to 0.1 or 0.01 based on your requirement.

Comment: I have long list to compare from. I can't specify 11 to 13 and so on.

Comment: @HusnainIqbal Is there any logic by which you can build your dict on?

Comment: No. I just have three different ranges. which reflect three different results. The ranges are long.

Comment: If you have a range then you can create a dict like this using `dict.fromkeys()` --> `dict.fromkeys(range(11,14),'C') `. This will create a dict as `{11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C'}`.Will this work for you?

Comment: @HusnainIqbal please see EDIT1 on how to create the dict from range

Comment: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I am getting this error.

Comment: @HusnainIqbal Which statement is giving this error?

Comment: fill_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(5700,5799.9999),'0.06')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204123/discussion-between-husnain-iqbal-and-davidbilla).

Comment: @HusnainIqbal see EDIT2

Comment: Thanks. I don't have system access now. I will try this as soon as I have hands on my system

Comment: The replace() command is not working correctly. it replaces the %age column with another. which is not even we are talking about.

Comment: Do you have any other columns with `HS CODE` values and those are getting replaced too?

Comment: NO. Only values in %age column are replaced.

Comment: Oh, did you mean non-NaN values in the '%age' column are also getting replaced? Try this `base1['%age'] = base1['%age'].fillna(base1['HS CODE'].map(fill_dict))` instead of the `replace()`

Comment: Yes. Non NaN are also replaced. with another columns values.

Comment: Try this `base1['%age'] = base1['%age'].fillna(base1['HS CODE'].map(fill_dict))` instead of the `replace()` statement

Answer (score 0):

Merge with left join, and then refill accordingly. 
UPDATE:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Column1'], how='left)
fill_dict = {11: 'A', 12: 'A', ...}
df1['Column1'] = df1['Column1'].fillna(df1['Column2'].apply(fill_dict))
```

Comment: Thank you. can you please explain fill_dict. I didn't get it being new to pandas and python.

Comment: Please take a look at the correction. 
Basically, *fillna* takes puts the values from pd.Series (in this case) in the argument into the NA holes of *df1['Column1']*.
*fill_dict* defines the mapping of the values to the letter, one by one.

Comment: please tell if I am rightly doing. 

````
fill_dict ={5700:5799 '0.06,6100:6299.9999'0.07''}
```

Comment: No, it would be wrong even syntactically. If you have a broad range, using a dict for mapping is wrong: you will need a function instead. Something along this line:
```def fill_func(x):
    if x >= 5700 and x < 5800:
        return 'A'
    elif x >= 6100 and x < 6300:
        return 'B'```
....
and pass it to *apply* in place of *fill_dict*

Comment: @OlegO - using `df.replace()` gives me the expected result instead of `.fillna().apply(dict)`

Comment: I proposed to pass Series to fillna, not to chain them with apply (which is plain incorrect).

Comment: Yes I meant that

Comment: you can replace `apply` with `map` which will work faster.

Comment: How do I do it?